# How make a SQL query with results of previous ID?

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT thread_id, COUNT(message) 
FROM xf_post 
GROUP BY message 
HAVING COUNT(message) > 1
```

and result of thread_id's and count's .

**Question:** How to make query to delete rows from other table with this thread_id's ?

Comment: No clue as to what you are asking.  Please provide example sample data, and complete details.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You are aggregating by `message`, but selecting `thread_id`.  In most databases, this would generate an error.  Please edit your question and describe what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

wrape up your query inside another select statement only select thread_id

```
Delete from yourtable where id in 
(
SELECT temp.thread_Id 
From    
 (  SELECT thread_id, COUNT(message) 
          FROM xf_post 
           GROUP BY message 
           HAVING  COUNT(message) > 1 
 ) temp      
)
```

you can also do this

```
 with cte as
 (
          SELECT thread_id
          FROM xf_post 
           GROUP BY message 
           HAVING  COUNT(message) > 1   
  )

 Delete from yourtable where id in 
  (
 select  thread_id from cte
  )
```

Comment: Brilliant. "temp" is table what i need to create?

Comment: nop . just replace `yourtable` from the table name which you want to delete

Answer (score 0):

The normally way to do this would be to use `in`.  If you want to delete threads that have more than one message:

```
delete from othertable
    where thread_id in (select thread_id
                        from xf_post 
                        group by thread_id
                        having COUNT(message) > 1 
                       );
```